# How to call return false in ajax requests page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to call `return false;` in ajax requests page ?

First, When i press `submit button` , It's will call `return checkform(this);`

And in `function checkform ( form )` will use ajax post to page `test.php`

In `test.php` can i use `return fales;` for break form `id="f1"`

I tested but not work, How can i do that ?

index.php

```
<form method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" id="f1">
<label>
    Your Username
</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<br>
<label>
    Your Password
</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">       
<br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign in"/>
<span id="mySpan_username_password"></span>
</form>



<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form )
{
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#f2').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#mySpan_username_password').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
}
</script>
<form id="f2">
    <input type="text" name="username_send_value" value="xx"/>  
    <input type="text" name="password_send_value" value="yy"/>  
</form>
```

test.php

```
<script>
return faalse;
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you add return: false; in the success of the ajax call or even at the end of checkform?

Answer (score 0):

You can return an `error` response to your ajax request e.g. `404`.

test.php

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `checkform` method shoots an ajax call and just move on. It doesn't wait for the ajax response, this is because of the default async behavior of ajax call.

In order to fix it, first you need to decide whether you want the ajax call async or not.

**if async:false**

```
   function checkform ( form )
   {
      var response=false;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async:false,//just add async:false here
        data: $('#f2').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#mySpan_username_password').html(data);
            response=true;
        }
    });
    return response;
 }
```

**if async:true**

pass callback as parameter and handle code in callback.

```
   function checkform ( form ,callback)
   {
      var response=false;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#f2').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#mySpan_username_password').html(data);
            callback(true);
        }
        error: function(data){
           callback(false);
        }
    });

 }
```

Method call:

```
 checkform(form,function(response){
 if(response===true)
 //....
 else
 //...
 });
```